# Syntax error in defining a stored procedure in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm defining a simple stored procedure in DB2 as follows but it gives me syntax error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Schema1.TESTSP1 ()
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN
if( exists(
    select 1 from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'Schema' and tabname = 'SPTEST'
)) then

drop table Schema.SPTEST ;  

create table Schema.SPTEST as
(select * from Schema.XYZ) WITH DATA ;

end if;


END P1
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Which error is returned?

Comment: it says 'no was expected after with' and when I put no (with no data) the error is gone but I need to create the table with data

Answer (score 0):

You *need* to study the IBM example stored procedures for SQL PL. 
Get the sample procedures working in your environment to build knowledge and skills.

You need to understand the difference between dynamic-sql and static-SQL and when to use either one.

You need to add exception handlers for any exceptions.

As you specified that it returns one result-set you need to open a cursor on that final result-set.

The examples below are for the Db2-LUW Version 11.1.3.3 CLP (command line processor), i.e. on Microsoft Windows that is the  what runs when you open db2cwadmin.bat, and on Linux/Unix the bash/ksh shell:

**Note**: the WITH DATA requires Db2-LUW 11.1.3.3, older versions supported only WITH NO DATA.  If you cannot upgrade, then use instead 'CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ...' followed by a separate statement INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...FROM ...

Here is a skeleton resembling your example, using static SQL on Db2-LUW V11.1.3.3:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Schema1.TESTSP1 ()
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN
    DECLARE SQLCODE integer;
    DECLARE table_exists integer default 0;

    select 1 into table_exists from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'SOMESCHEMA' and tabname = 'SPTEST';

    if table_exists = 1
    then 
        drop table SOMESCHEMA.SPTEST ;  

        create table SOMESCHEMA.SPTEST as (select * from SCHEMA.SPTEST ) with data ;

    end if;


END P1
@
```

Here is a skeleton which resembles your example but uses dynamic-SQL on Db2-LUW V11.1.3.3, which would be useful if you don't know in advance the table/column names and they are available in parameters to the stored procedure (not shown) in which case you can dynamically build the SQL and execute it:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Schema1.TESTSP1 ()
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN
    DECLARE SQLCODE integer;
    DECLARE table_exists integer default 0;

    select 1 into table_exists from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'SOMESCHEMA' and tabname = 'SPTEST';

    if table_exists = 1
    then 
        execute immediate('drop table SOMESCHEMA.SPTEST') ;  

        execute immediate('create table SOMESCHEMA.SPTEST as (select * from SCHEMA.SPTEST ) with data') ;

    end if;


END P1
@
```

Comment: when using the code you provided for STATIC SQL, I'm getting the same error regarding the 'WITH DATA'

Comment: works fine for me, what is the output of the `db2level` command on your operating-system?

Comment: I'm using Data Studio and it shows the error message and it doesn't deploy

Comment: Please answer the question: what's the output of the `db2level` command on the Db2-server.   Also, always give the *exact* error number (sqlcode, sqlstate).

Comment: DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "TEST1")
uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11012" with level identifier
"0203010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.1.2020.1393", "s1706091900",
"DYN1701310100WIN64", and Fix Pack "2".
Product is installed at "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB" with DB2 Copy Name "DB2COPY1".

Comment: Answer updated 'WITH DATA' works with V11.1.3.3 slightly newer version than your v11.1.2.2.